Partition these words into 4 groups











open
square
simple
odd


total
cyclic
closed
well


trivial
prime
partial
analytic


meager
weird
perfect
dense




My solution:
First group

 set:
 open set,
 closed set,
 meager set,
 dense set

Second group

 number:
 square number,
 odd number,
 prime number,
 weird number

Third group

 group:
 simple group,
 cyclic group,
 analytic group,
 perfect group

Fourth group

 order:
 total order,
 well-order,
 trivial order,
 partial order

Alternative Solutions
(credits Tim Seifert)

 rotate analytic->dense->trivial->analytic

 set:
 open set,
 closed set,
 meager set,
 analytic set

 number:
 square number,
 odd number,
 prime number,
 weird number

 group:
 simple group,
 cyclic group,
 trivial group,
 perfect group

 order:
 total order,
 well-order,
 dense order,
 partial order


 swap perfect with analytic in second solution

 set:
 open set,
 closed set,
 meager set,
 perfect set

 number:
 square number,
 odd number,
 prime number,
 weird number

 group:
 simple group,
 cyclic group,
 trivial group,
 analytic group,

 order:
 total order,
 well-order,
 dense order,
 partial order


Nice! Although it seems that there are several other ways of dividing them up, for instance by rotating analytic->dense->trivial->analytic. And, starting from that second solution, you could also swap perfect with analytic.
